# jQuery Datepicker won't change value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use the datepicker function from jquery. Now I have integrated a inline calendar. It should be possible to click on one day in the shown month and then submit a form or change the url. I need the new date added to the url so i can jump to this date.

But my code won't change the value of the input - and i don't know why.

Here my code:

In the head area:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/bootstrap-datepicker.de.js"></script>
```

The HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="minicalendar"></div>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="submitDate" id="submitDate" />
  </div>
</form>
```

The JS:

```
$('.minicalendar').datepicker({
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
    todayBtn: true,
    language: "de",
    calendarWeeks: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      $('#submitDate').val(dateText);
   }
});
```

Do you know why? I was searching for a time now but I wasn't able to find a solution that works ...

Thanks.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle ? and why do you include js twice (in different versions)?

Comment: Are you saying, after picking a date and submitting the form, you are not able to pick the date again?

Comment: @dwrza you are right i included jquery twice - that's wrong! I now changed it ... now i include jquery-ui in the second line.

Comment: @rps no when i pick one date, the value of the input not changes

Comment: The code you have posted in the question is working fine though, http://jsbin.com/dukimuxe/1/edit. Check you browser console for any error

Comment: OK I just realized, if I don't include the bootstrap-datepicker.js, then everything works fine. Without that the value of the input field is changing. But I need this tool because of the german calendar and the responsibility. Do you have an idea why this file is creating this error?

Answer (score 2):

You are binding the datepicker to a`div` instead of an`input`.

```
<input id="datepicker" />

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
     //...
});
```

You also don't need to change the input text with the `onSelect` event. The widget will do thix automatically.

Comment: OK ... but with this solution I have to click into the input area to open the calendar and pick a date. I want the calendar to be visible all the time. So I only have to click one of this days and then the form should be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submitDate').datepicker({
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
    todayBtn: true,
    language: "de",
    calendarWeeks: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      $('#submitDate').val(dateText);
   }
});
```

Use this. Datepicker won't bind to a `<div>` it has to be an `<input>` element. Check this [**link**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for  more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from JQuery UI DatePicker :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

The input id has to be the same that the element selected in JQuery.